# How to find phrases in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My text file is this:

```
123 Numbers 4.5
456 Words 6.7
789 Sentences 8.9
```

And my code is this:

```
s = open('test.txt', 'r')
file = s.read()
numbers, words, decimals = [], [], []
```

I've gotten thus far, and i'm trying to work out how to create a list for all the numbers, words and decimals in the file. I've heard you can use the split method, so i tried this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers, words, decimals = f.split(","), f.split(","), f.split(",")
```

I did this assuming it would split every time it encountered a space, but that didn't happen, i just got the error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any help would be appreciated. If any elaboration is necessary on what i want to do please tell me, i'm aware this may have been worded poorly.

Comment: it should be `line.split(",")` instead of `f.split(",")`

Comment: I just tried that, and though it got rid of the error, it still isn't doing what i wanted it to do. If i were to print numbers, words and decimals each list contains only one item being just the last line. So, each list contains: '789 Sentences 8.9'. Additionally, this is all one value in the list. I want the numbers list to contain all the numbers at the start of the line, words to contain all the words in the middle, and decimals to contain all the decimals at the end. Each should also be a separate value in the list.

Comment: you should append these values to the list..use `numbers.append(line.split(",")[0]),words.append(line.split(",")[1]),decimals.append(line.split(",")[2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the text file you've posted does not have commas separating the columns, so splitting the string at commas won't work.  If you can trust that every line of the file will be identical in structure, then you can simply change your code to be

```
numbers, words, decimals = [], [], []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        number, word, decimal = line.split() 
        numbers.append(number)
        words.append(word)
        decimals.append(decimal)
```

Comment: Each decimal will have a trailing newline because `line` includes the trailing newline.  Change `line.split(" ")` to `line.split()` and the trailing whitespace will fall away.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers, words, decimals = zip(*(line.split() for line in f))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to split each line into fields

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        number, word, decimal = line.split()  # split on whitespace as indicated by your example file which does not use commas
        numbers.append(int(number))
        words.append(word)
        decimals.append(float(decimal))
```

If you really intend to use ral decimals than you should use `decimal.Decimal` instead of `float`.

Unless you are constrained in some way, I'd recommend using some library designed for working with tabular data, e.g. pandas where all this would be just

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('test.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `line.split` and not `f.split` since you're splitting the line and not the file. Also, you're separating your file on commas but the example file is separated by spaces? If it is separated by spaces you need to use `line.split(" ")` Also, using `with open() as f` you don't need to open you're file beforehand or close it afterwards as it sorts that for you. Also, you were saving the entire line split array to each variable and overwriting them each time. Overall code:

```
numbers, words, decimals = [], [], []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers.append(line.split(" ")[0])
        words.append(line.split(" ")[1])
        decimals.append(line.split(" ")[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly what you should be looking at is actually [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/). That will give you an insight in how to tokenize your text based either on words or sentences. The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
a,b,c=[],[],[]
with open('new.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    m=line.split()
    a.append(m[0])
    b.append(m[1])
    c.append(m[2])
print a,b,c
```

Check if this is what you wanted to achieve.